# How to assign multiple google_storage_bucket_iam_member on multiple service-accounts

Tags: google-cloud-storage, terraform-provider-gcp, terraform0.12+

Using Terraform 0.12.24

I create multiple service-account, and want to assign each of those with Owner Permission to a list of buckets, and running into numerous problems

```
# Service-accounts created with random-integer suffix
resource "google_service_account" "sample_accounts" {
  for_each     = {for proj in var.target_projects: proj => proj}
  account_id   = "cost-saver-${random_integer.sa_id[each.key].result}" 
  project      = var.project
  display_name = "service account for ${each.key}"
}
```

```
resource "google_storage_bucket_iam_member" "shared_buckets_iam" {
  for_each    = {for svc in google_service_account.sample_accounts: svc.email => svc.email}
  bucket      = "${var.shared_project}-shared-files"
  role        = "roles/storage.legacyBucketOwner"
  member      = "serviceAccount:${each.value}"
  depends_on  = [google_service_account.sample_accounts]

}
```

Since the service-accounts are created dynamically and I want to use them in the same terraform apply run, I run into this problem

```
Error: Invalid for_each argument

  on main.tf line 138, in resource "google_storage_bucket_iam_member" "shared_buckets_iam":
 138:   for_each    = {for svc in google_service_account.sample_accounts: svc.email => svc.email}

The "for_each" value depends on resource attributes that cannot be determined
until apply, so Terraform cannot predict how many instances will be created.
To work around this, use the -target argument to first apply only the
resources that the for_each depends on.
```

Can I please get some assistance?

Comment: What do you look for assistance? The Terraform error message is clear enough, isn't it?

Comment: Well terraforms suggestion is that I use -target to create one resource and then the other, which is prob the worse approach and defeats the entire purpose of automation. If I can create other items such as google_dns_records and retrieve their attributes on the fly, then there must be a way to retrieve google_service_account too.

Comment: Why do you need to create a set of service account?

Comment: It’s an application requirement. Each used to deploy a cloud function in a different project later on

Comment: Ok, and you don't want to repeat the code, only loop, even for deploying functions, right?

Comment: Yes the idea was that I do a single terraform init, followed by apply and it creates all the resources for my respective projects in one go